# Yii - Counting and relations

Tags: yii, relational-database

I currently have a table setup for the opinion (either 1 or 0) of a user on an article.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opinion_article` 
(
`id`                INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`uid`               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /* user with an opinion on the article */
`aid`               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /* article ID */
`opinion`           BOOL NOT NULL, /* opinion on the article, 1 = good, 0 = bad */
FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
FOREIGN KEY (`aid`) REFERENCES `article`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
UNIQUE (`uid`, `aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to get a user's "article score," which is just how many other users have voted their article as good. The trick is that a user can have many articles. Is there a way to do this without returning all opinions on all articles for a user, then using a for loop to check for opinion==1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Article model, add the following relation:

```
'score'=>array(self::STAT, 'OpinionArticle', 'aid', 'condition'=>'opinion=1')
```

Then `$Article->score` should return that number for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any way to make it $user->score though? Or for that do I need to use a loop to count all the $article->score for the user?

Comment: Actually, I thought of a nice way to do it similar to this. I'll add it as a response so others can see it

Answer (score 0):

Along with the answer left by Willem, I came to this nice solution. Basically I just added an extra field in my 'opinion_article' table for the author's ID.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opinion_article` 
(
`id`                INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`uid`               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`aid`               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /* article ID */
`author_id`         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /* the author of the article's ID */
`opinion`           BOOL NOT NULL, /* opinion on the article, 1 = good, 0 = bad */
FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
FOREIGN KEY (`aid`) REFERENCES `article`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
UNIQUE (`uid`, `aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then, in my User model I added this line:

```
        'articleScore'=>array(self::STAT, 'OpinionArticle', 'author_id', 'condition'=>'opinion=1'),
```

Then I can just get the article score by calling $user->articleScore